# MySQL Optimization on my server

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos-7, mysqltuner

I have an active server running around 80-100 active websites. I would like to optimize the server and possibly reduce the amount of RAM and optimize my MySQL settings. I have 30 GB of RAM assigned and 12 Cores, CentOS7. I ran MySQLTuner and got this recommendations:

MySQL Tuner Recommendations:

```
MySQLTuner 1.7.19 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[!!] Your MySQL version 5.5.66-MariaDB is EOL software!  Upgrade soon!
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Performance Metrics -----

[--] Up for: 31d 2h 31m 13s (309M q [115.168 qps], 1M conn, TX: 2455G, RX: 159G
[--] Reads / Writes: 95% / 5%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 29.3G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 24.6G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 13.7G global + 22.4M per thread (500 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 14.5G (49.49% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 24.6G (84.00% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (96/309M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 7% (38/500)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.59%  (7936/1345660)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance

[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 47.6% (263M cached / 553M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 208303
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (431 temp sorts / 2M sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 37167
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 6% (31K on disk / 457K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (38 created / 1M connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 0% (400 open / 1M opened)
[!!] table_definition_cache(400) is lower than number of tables(34357)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (4/2K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (45M immediate / 45M locks)

-------- Performance schema ---------

[--] Performance schema is disabled.
[--] Memory used by P_S: 0B
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics --------

[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 12 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (5.5.66-MariaDB)

-------- MyISAM Metrics -----------

[!!] Key buffer used: 18.7% (588M used / 3B cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 2.9G/750.1M
[!!] Read Key buffer hit rate: 7.2% (78K cached / 72K reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 2.1% (2K cached / 60 writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------

[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 10.0G/6.1G
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 1.0G * 2/10.0G should be equal to 25%
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.99% (2352937489 hits/ 2353198127 total
[OK] InnoDB Write log efficiency: 96.40% (264231435 hits/ 274111596 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 9880161 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------

[--] AriaDB is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/1B
[OK] Aria pagecache hit rate: 100.0% (5M cached / 2K reads)

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------

[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ---------

[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics --------

[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: STATEMENT
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ----------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err file
    Control error line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err file
    Increasing the query_cache size over 128M may reduce performance
    We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.
             See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html
             (specially the conclusions at the bottom of the page).
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: https://bit.ly/1mi7c4C
    Read this before increasing for MariaDB 
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/optimizing-table_open_cache/
    This is MyISAM only table_cache scalability problem, InnoDB not affected.
    See more details here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49177
    This bug already fixed in MySQL 5.7.9 and newer MySQL versions.
    Beware that open_files_limit (2505) variable
    should be greater than table_open_cache (400)

Variables to adjust:
    SET innodb_stats_on_metadata = OFF
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_size (> 500M) [see warning above]
    join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    table_open_cache (> 400)
    table_definition_cache(400) > 34357 or -1 (autosizing if supported)
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=10)
```

my.cnf and other cnfs

```
[mysqld]

innodb_file_per_table
slow_query_log
long_query_time=5
slow_query_log_file=/opt/db-backups1/mysqllog/mysql_slow.log



[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0


#######################################################################

#innodb_force_recovery=4

#######################################################################

max_connections = 500
thread_cache_size=2000
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
key_buffer_size = 3000M
read_buffer_size = 16M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 256M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 16M
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 256M
myisam_repair_threads = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10G
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 100M
query_cache_limit = 60M
query_cache_size = 500M
query_cache_type = 1
```

Thanks for any recommendations, they are greatly appreciated. The error log is showing because I migrated some MyISAM databases physically from an old server and some tables that were empty did not have any corresponding table files and the system thinks that it's missing. I think the solution for that will be to export and import the MyISAM databases with the proper tool instead of physically copying it. It is important to mention there are dates and months where the access rate rises exponentially and the server should be ready for this heavy load.

EDIT 1: ADDING top and ulimit RESULT

```
[root@www ~]# cat topres.txt
top - 16:55:44 up 34 days,  3:59,  1 user,  load average: 0,02, 0,08, 0,12
Tasks: 204 total,   3 running, 201 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4,6 us,  1,5 sy,  0,0 ni, 93,9 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem : 30714928 total,  3197812 free, 13266944 used, 14250172 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8257532 total,  7476220 free,   781312 used. 16947012 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
14463 apache    20   0  674920  42676  19516 R  43,8  0,1   0:00.34 httpd
 2965 mysql     20   0   16,3g  12,0g   7744 S  18,8 41,0   1117:52 mysqld
14496 root      20   0  162048   2296   1540 R   6,2  0,0   0:00.01 top
    1 root      20   0  190980   3228   2032 S   0,0  0,0   4:07.76 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.91 kthreadd
```

ulimit -a:

```
[root@www ~]# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 119888
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 119888
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

EDIT 2: Adding mysql tuner results after high traffic on our server. Any recommendations are greatly appreciated. We have changed the procesor amount to 16 virtual cpus.

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.7.19 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[!!] Your MySQL version 5.5.66-MariaDB is EOL software!  Upgrade soon!
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ----------------------------------------------                                                                                                                     --------------------
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err exists
[--] Log file: /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err(29M)
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err is readable.
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err is smaller than 32 Mb
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err contains 8 warning(s).
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err contains 5699 error(s).
[--] 8 start(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err
[--] 1) 200220 19:00:40 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 2) 200220 18:42:35 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 3) 200114 12:55:56 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 4) 200114 12:54:30 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 5) 200114  9:43:11 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 6) 200114  9:39:02 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 7) 200110 15:38:03 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 8) 200110 15:28:21 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 7 shutdown(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err
[--] 1) 200220 19:00:35 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 2) 200114 12:55:30 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 3) 200114 12:52:41 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 4) 200114  9:42:12 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 5) 200114  9:38:55 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 6) 200110 15:37:55 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 7) 200110 15:22:13 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +Aria +BLACKHOLE +CSV +FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 290.0M (Tables: 3)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 6.3G (Tables: 33793)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: ON
[!!] Stat are updated during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned


-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] NO SECURITY CVE FOUND FOR YOUR VERSION

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 10d 13h 51m 8s (89M q [97.936 qps], 313K conn, TX: 627G, RX: 68G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 95% / 5%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 29.3G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 24.6G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 13.7G global + 22.4M per thread (500 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 14.0G (47.84% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 24.6G (84.00% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (1/89M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 3% (16/500)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (1/313391)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 47.7% (76M cached / 161M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 172476
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (40 temp sorts / 658K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 6650
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 32% (71K on disk / 220K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (16 created / 313K connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 0% (400 open / 509K opened)
[!!] table_definition_cache(400) is lower than number of tables(33899)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (4/2K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (12M immediate / 12M locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance schema is disabled.
[--] Memory used by P_S: 0B
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 16 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (5.5.66-MariaDB)

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.7% (588M used / 3B cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 2.9G/370.0K
[!!] Read Key buffer hit rate: 63.9% (366 cached / 132 reads)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 10.0G/6.3G
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 1.0G * 2/10.0G should be equal to 25%
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.92% (548727530 hits/ 549178090 total)
[OK] InnoDB Write log efficiency: 96.50% (76869307 hits/ 79658631 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 2789324 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/1B
[OK] Aria pagecache hit rate: 100.0% (295K cached / 124 reads)

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: STATEMENT
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err file
    Control error line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err file


    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    Increasing the query_cache size over 128M may reduce performance
    We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.
             See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html
             (specially the conclusions at the bottom of the page).
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: https://bit.ly/1mi7c4C
    Read this before increasing for MariaDB https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/optimizing-table_open_cache/
    This is MyISAM only table_cache scalability problem, InnoDB not affected.
    See more details here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49177
    This bug already fixed in MySQL 5.7.9 and newer MySQL versions.
    Beware that open_files_limit (2505) variable
    should be greater than table_open_cache (400)
Variables to adjust:
    SET innodb_stats_on_metadata = OFF
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_size (> 500M) [see warning above]
    join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    tmp_table_size (> 16M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
    table_open_cache (> 400)
    table_definition_cache(400) > 33899 or -1 (autosizing if supported)
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=10)
```

CPU and memory overview for the month.
[image: Month CPU & Memory Overview]

CPU and memory overview for a day.
[image: Day CPU & Memory Overview]

Comment: Sites? Do you mean websites?

Comment: yes that's what i meant to say, websites.

Comment: Please post the complete MySQLTuner report.  Only part of the report were posted.  And please post TEXT report from TOP and ulimit -a so we can see your OS limits.

Comment: Why reduce the RAM? You have 30 available and using only 10G. Also, are you using MyISAM tables at all? I don't like to trust all my performance review on MySQLtunner.

Comment: We have limited memory on our servers, this is located on a virtual machine. Since I only use 10 GB, the other 20 could be relocated to other machines that need more RAM. The CPU usage is very low, I believe 5%, that's why I didn't put the top. I omited only one or two parts (like security that I have checked) from the MySQLTunner report. The main thing i´d like to optimize is the RAM usage.

Comment: I have added the top and ulimit -a results

Comment: By the way it is important to mention there are dates and months where the access rate rises exponentially and the server should be ready for this heavy load.

Comment: With a 10GB restriction and a 100GB server needed, you can not be prepared to serve the known heavy load.  Moving a mountain of data requires more than a shovel.  Failure to post complete MySQLTuner report limits our ability to assist you.

Answer (score 2):

The tuner results on innodb say you have 6.1G of data therefore innodb_buffer_pool_size could be reduced to say 5G and see what impact that has on the "InnoDB Read buffer efficiency".

This will reduce the 16.3g ram usage down to 11.3G for mysql. Given you currently have total ~13G usage I suggest its pretty safe to drop the allocation down to ~16G.

"Highest usage of available connections" shows your max used connections at 38 which is significantly lower than 500 upper limit that you've set. I'd suggest dropping the maximum down to 100 as you're intent on dropping the ram. Its quite possible there won't be sufficient memory for 500 connections.

query cache should be disabled. Its a scale-ability problem and was only getting a 43% efficiency anyway.

long_query_time of 5 is far too big. A 5 second page fetch isn't probably acceptable so you make this lower. After all the tuner results say there is only 80 queries in the slow query log.

Take a look at the slow queries. Making them faster means that a higher load is possible on the same number of connections available. e.g. if a 1 second query is made to run in 30ms, then more of those can happen per second.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I appreciate your suggestions and will apply them on the server.

Answer (score 0):

34357 tables??  What the heck is going on?  Perhaps WordPress, with one db per customer?  Or something like that?  Anyway, you need to set `table_open_cache` much higher than 400.  Try for 4000.  Ditto for `table_definition_cache`.  You may need to increase what the OS lets each process have; see `ulimit -n`.

Lower `long_query_time` to `1` (seconds) and turn on the slowlog.  That will let you catch some naughty queries.

115 QPS?  That is rather low.  What problem are you seeing?

The Query Cache is of dubious use.  `query_cache_size = 500M` means that it spends a lot of time in each "prune"; and with dozens of prunes per second, I suggest that it is doing more harm than good.  Plan A:  Drop that to 50M.  Plan B:  drop it to 0.  (In most "production" servers, the QC does more harm than good.)

`thread_cache_size=2000` -- Unnecessarily large.  Drop it to 100.

"possibly reduce the amount of RAM" -- Why?  You are not using all of it now, and 'big' settings (`key_buffer_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size`) are bigger than necessary.  That is, you have room for growth with those settings, and there is even room to raise them.  Or do you mean that you are thinking about shrinking to a cheaper machine?  If so, I should look over the numbers with that in mind; preferably after doing the analysis below.

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis for getting another opinion on the settings, plus getting the slowlog analyzed.

Comment: Thank you Rick. Yes, we found out the amount of tables is due to the way the Drupal scheme works. We will be implementing the recommendations starting March 1st and will keep you updated. I believe we won't reduce the RAM size after all the comments on this post, instead we will just optimize MySQL for better performance and reliability. This machine is a virtual machine. Thanks for your time on commenting this post it is very much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

From linux Command Prompt,

```
ulimit -n 16000 and press Enter to allow more than 1024 Open File handles
```

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section from available info

```
max_connections=100  # from 500 since max_used_connections was 38 in 31 days
thread_cache_size=100  # from 2000 to conserve RAM only 38 threads_created in 31d
key_buffer_size=1G  # from ~3G to MyISAM index size is 750M
read_buffer_size=512K  # from 16M to reduce handler_read_next RPS
read_rnd_buffer_size=192K  # from 4M to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS
```

You will find these configuration changes will REDUCE CPU busy significantly.

View my profile, Network profile for free downloadable Utility Scripts to improve performance.  More Global Variable changes would also improve performance.

Comment: Thanks Wilson I appreciate your recomendations and will apply most of them on the server.

Comment: @DAVIDANDRÉSTAPIAMOSCOSO Are you making any progress?  There are a lot of people making suggestions.  Be careful with your decisions and monitor the progress a day at a time.  No more than one change a day so you know which one has been harmful.

Comment: Hello Wilson, thanks for following the post. Currently we can't make any changes till 1st of March. Right now we are going through the high access rate I mentioned. We increased the amount of cores to 16. We also found out that the amount of tables is due to the way the Drupal scheme works. I will run the MySQL Tuner again and update the post and will also be making all the changes starting March 1st one by one like you recommended. I am very thankful with all the people that are replying to this post and every recommendation will be analyzed/considered.

Comment: @DAVIDANDRÉSTAPIAMOSCOSO Our Utility Scripts will help you with performance and you will find using findfragtables.sql monthly will remind you of the need to OPTIMIZE tables with FREESPACE greater than 10% of DATASPACE.  find-redundant-indexes.sql should be run every 90 days to identify the need to reduce CPU use and data storage requirements by considering getting rid of the same indexes.

Comment: thanks, I have updated the post with new MySQL Tuner results. Today I will start to add the optimization recommendations.

Comment: @DAVIDANDRÉSTAPIAMOSCOSO Thanks for the new MySQL Tuner results.  Looking forward to an update after all suggestions applied, then a week later post an updated report, please.

Comment: @DAVIDANDRÉSTAPIAMOSCOSO    Have you made progress?  Please get a new MySQLTuner report and post with the date of the run for your audience.